# GUI tools for viewing/editing Apache Parquet

Tags: apache, hadoop, parquet

I have some Apache Parquet file. I know I can execute `parquet file.parquet` in my shell and view it in terminal. But I would like some GUI tool to view Parquet files in more user-friendly format. Does such kind of program exist?

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74079053/1719931) on how to use DBeaver to view parquet files.

Answer (score 24):

There is [Tad](https://www.tadviewer.com/) utility, which is cross-platform. Allows you to open Parquet files and also pivot them and export to CSV. Uses DuckDB as it's backend. More info on the [DuckDB page](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/guides/data_viewers/tad):

GH here:
https://github.com/antonycourtney/tad

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for thx @Gabe. It works on macos 2!

Comment: Great suggestion! Running on masOS Ventura 13.1 for viewing parquet files

Answer (score 21):

GUI option for Windows, Linux, MAC

You can now use **DBeaver** to

- view parquet data
- view metadata and statistics
- run sql query on one or multiple files. (supports glob expressions)
- generate new parquet files.

DBeaver leverages DuckDB driver to perform operations on parquet file. Features like Projection and predicate pushdown are also supported by DuckDB.

Simply [create an in-memory instance of DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/sql_editors/dbeaver) using Dbeaver and run the queries like mentioned in this [document](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet). Right now Parquet and [CSV](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/csv) is supported.

Here is a Youtube video that explains the same - https://youtu.be/j9_YmAKSHoA

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Check out this utility. Works for all windows versions: https://github.com/mukunku/ParquetViewer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried it, but for parquet with complex structure, like a JSON, this type of utility doesn't work. It works with parquet with a plain structure, like a CSV.

Comment: I tried this one as well. In my parquet file it seems to mess up every 2nd row by inserting an incorrect 0 value in the first column and moving all the correct values down a row for each 0 it inserts. I tried the BigDataFileViewer which can view my files correctly but only if you open the file twice. The first time it throws an error about incorrect magic numbers in the tail, but then seemingly works correctly when you open the file a 2nd time. The schema and table data seem correct.

Comment: @Roochiedoor maybe open an issue ticket on the repo with the example file?

Comment: @Sal logged a ticket at https://github.com/mukunku/ParquetViewer/issues/20 just now

Comment: I like it, it's fast and simple, i just want to (pre)view tabular parquet files

Comment: [Tevis](https://singtel-dataco.github.io/Tevis/) has been heavily tested with large parquet files, with very complex and nested data structures and works perfectly fine. Give it a try! [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5NiLai9MT8&t=544s) here.

Answer (score 5):

There is a GUI tool to view [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) and also other binary format data like [ORC](https://orc.apache.org/) and [AVRO](https://avro.apache.org/). It's pure Java application so that can be run at Linux, Mac and also Windows. Please check [Bigdata File Viewer](https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer) for details.

It supports complex data type like array, map, struct etc. And you can save the read file in CSV format.

[image]

Comment: Currently the tool does not work without fiddling with java, since javafx seems to be missing. see https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer/issues/25

Answer (score 4):

Actually I found some Windows 10 specific solution. However, I'm working on Linux Mint 18 so I would like to some Linux (or ideally cross-platform) GUI tool. Is there some other GUI tool?

https://www.channels.elastacloud.com/channels/parquet-net/how-about-viewing-parquet-files

Comment: Is there anything similar for Windows 8 ?

Answer (score 2):

There is webassembly viewer which works fully offline: https://aloneguid.github.io/parquet-online/

[image]

Comment: Link gives 404?

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains (IntelliJ, PyCharm etc) has a plugin for this, if you have a professional version: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12494-big-data-tools

Comment: they only display basic data types and fall short on anything a bit more complex like structures, lists, maps etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Tab Lab [Parquet Viewer](https://www.tablab.app/view/parquet). It lets you view and filter Parquet files. You can also [make graphs](https://www.tablab.app/graphs) and [query parquet with sql](https://www.tablab.app/sql/parquet).

[Tab Lab Parquet Viewer gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ksH1.gif)