# Convert parquet to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parquet

I want to convert a parquet file into a CSV file.
I am running this program:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('filename.parquet')

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

But it is showing the following error:

> ArrowIOError : Invalid parquet file. Corrupt footer

Comment: try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201799/pandas-cannot-read-parquet-files-created-in-pyspark

Comment: Have you looked into parquet-cli?

Comment: Could you convert your parquet file to csv with parquet-cli? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57576367/1352781