# How to aggregate results of an IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, aggregate, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

I want to ask if there is a plan or exists a method to aggregate the return(s) of an `IAsyncEnumerable`? So given the below method why is there no terse way to aggregate its result?

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<bool> GenerateAsyncEnumerable(int range)
{
     foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, range))
     {
           await Task.Delay(500 * x);
           yield return x % 2 == 0;
     }
}
```

**Current Scenario**

```
public async Task Main()
{

    bool accum = true;
    await foreach (var item in GenerateAsyncEnumerable(3))
    {
         accum &= item;
         //have some side effects on each particular item of the sequence
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Accumulator:{accum}");
}
```

**Desired Scenario**

I would like to aggregate the results of the `IAsyncEnumerable` given a custom aggregation `Func`

```
public async Main()
{

    bool result = await foreach (var item in GenerateAsyncEnumerable(3).Aggregate(true, (x, y) => x & y))
    {
        //have some side effects on each particular item of the sequence
    }
}
```

**P.S** I do not like (in the first scenario) that I have to add an extra local variable `accum` that collects the results of the enumerable. Have I missed something, is there some syntactic sugar that I am not aware of ?

Comment: You could write your own extension method that returns a new `IAsyncEnumerable`?

Comment: All those methods are part of `System.Linq.Async`, including [AggregateAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Aggregate.cs).

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned there are extensions methods under in library `System.Linq.Async`. One of them is `ToAsyncEnumerable` but exercise caution when using it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956623/using-iasyncenumerable-with-dapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `AggregateAsync` method, from the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) package:

```
bool result = await GenerateAsyncEnumerable(3).AggregateAsync(true, (x, y) => x & y);
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
```

Output:

> Result: False

Answer (score 3):

The [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) package developed by the [ReactiveX](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async) team provides [LINQ operators](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators) for `IAsyncEnumerable` that are equivalent to those LINQ provides for `IEnumerable`.

This includes the common operators like [Select()](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Select.cs), [Where()](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Where.cs), [Take()](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Take.cs) etc. `Aggregate` is implemented by [AggregateAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Aggregate.cs).

The overloads are similar to [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8)
, which means you can write:

```
bool result=await GenerateAsyncEnumerable(3).AggregateAsync(true, (x, y) => x & y);
```

`AggregateAsync` is named this way because it consumes the entire enumerable and produces a single result. It needs an `await` call to work.  Other operators like `Select` though, accept an `IAsyncEnumerable` and produce a new one. There's no need to await them.

You can use this naming convention to find the Linq.Async operators you need based on the name of the equivalent `Enumerable` operator

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class AsyncEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TOut> AggregateAsync<T, TOut>(
        this IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncCollection,
        TOut seed, 
        Func<TOut, T, TOut> func) 
    {
        await foreach (var item in asyncCollection) 
        {
            seed = func(seed, item);
        }
        return seed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it also needs `ConfigureAwait(false)` and `WithCancellation` to be perfect.